# cUrl on proxy server returns state 200, cUrl through proxy return 403

Tags: curl, proxy

I currently am trying to curl a website through proxy.
I setup a proxy server using Squid.
My squid.conf configuration is:

```
acl allowed_ip src xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (ip of the other server)
http_access allow allowed_ip
http_access deny all
```

When I ssh on my proxy server i can do:

```
curl http://www.submarino.com.br -i
```

and i get:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
X-Powered-By: JSF/1.2
x-tid: CATALOGO-05ada7f1-ed40-4192-b487-47e658111844
Cache-Control: max-age=698
Expires: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 18:48:49 GMT
Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 18:37:11 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Set-Cookie: MobileOptOut=1; path=/; domain=submarino.com.br
Set-Cookie: b2wChannel=INTERNET; path=/; domain=submarino.com.br
Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
```

But if i try to curl through my other server, using:

```
curl 'http://www.submarino.com.br' --proxy 128.199.209.72:3128 -v
```

I get:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.submarino.com.br/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xx...
* Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) port xxxx (#0)
> GET http://www.submarino.com.br/ HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.submarino.com.br
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
* Server AkamaiGHost is not blacklisted
< Server: AkamaiGHost
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 274
< Expires: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 18:31:16 GMT
< Date: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 18:31:16 GMT
< Set-Cookie: MobileOptOut=1; path=/; domain=submarino.com.br
< Set-Cookie: b2wChannel=INTERNET; path=/; domain=submarino.com.br
< Vary: Accept-Encoding, User-Agent
< X-Cache: MISS from ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01
< X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01:3128
< Via: 1.1 ubuntu-512mb-sgp1-01 (squid/3.5.12)
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host ----------- left intact
```

From the result it seems that I'm connecting throught the proxy. I get the same result when curling without proxy. Can anyone please shed some light on this?

**UPDATE:**

I set up basic auth on my proxy but the errors are the same. I can connect to the proxy but the curl fails on that given URL (www.submarino.com.br).
Other url work fine.

I tried to curl through the same proxy on my localhost.

```
GET http://www.submarino.com.br/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.submarino.com.br
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic cHJvbW9jb246cHJvbW9jb25ieWdlbmV6emkyMDE2
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

And on my server

```
Proxy auth using Basic with user 'xxxxxx'
> GET http://www.submarino.com.br/ HTTP/1.1
> Proxy-Authorization: Basic cHJvbW9jb246cHJvbW9jb25ieWdlbmV6emkyMDE2
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: www.submarino.com.br
> Accept: */*
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```

Basically they're working the same when I don't proxy the curl request.

Answer (score 0):

Your squid proxy host is denying requests. You might need to authenticate with the proxy.

Comment: Actually this response is the one I get if curl directly to that url on my normal server. I says "Connected to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx) port xxxx (#0)". I xxx the ip just for privacy purposes.